# Change GameObject pivot point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity object not rotating in center. It was fine until an hour, I don't believe I changed the code or anything. I have also tried messing with the pivot/centre buttons on the top left but nothing is helping. The game Object is not rotating in the middle.

Rotator Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 100f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default space of the `Rotate` function `Space.Self`. You should provide `Space.World` to its third parameter to make it rotate in world space.

```
transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

If this does not solve your problem, you have to open your model up in any 3D application such as Maya and reset/center the pivot point then re-import it into Unity.

You can also use another GameObject as parent of this GameObject you want to rotate to solve this pivot issues.

**1**.Create a new GameObject

**2**.Move it to the center position of the object you are rotating.

**3**.Once you are fine with that location, drag that object you are rotating under the GameObject created in **#1**. The GameObject you are rotating should now be a child of that GameObject created in **#1**.

You can now rotate the GameObject created in **#1** instead.

Although, I hate doing that but it works too. I suggest using a 3D application to do it to move the pivot point.

Comment: Agreed that it's probably the modeling program's origin-as-center and that recentering it there will fix things.